# How to install puttygen version >=0.75 in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, putty

I have file .ppk version 3 but seem like putty version must be >=0.75 to handle this file .ppk version 3.

The information I have found: [https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/ppk3.html](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/wishlist/ppk3.html)

I have read and try many way to install putty version 0.75 in ubuntu 20.04, but seem like ubuntu 20.04 just support putty version <= 0.73.

Can someone let me know how to install putty version >=0.75 in ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: If you don't find a Debian repository that provides pre-compiled Putty you could download the Linux source code and compile it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following commands on the terminal

```
# If putty is installed, uninstall it
sudo apt remove putty-tools

# Download the unix source code of the 0.76 version of putty
mkdir putty_source_code
cd putty_source_code
wget https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.76/putty-0.76.tar.gz

# Extract the unix code
tar -xvf putty-0.76.tar.gz
cd putty-0.76

# Compile the unix code
./configure
make
sudo cp puttygen /usr/bin/

# Check if the version was installed correctly
puttygen --version # Should output something similar to `puttygen: Release 0.76`

# Change to the directory with the .ppk file
cd <dir_with_ppk_key> 
puttygen <ppk_key_name.ppk> -O private-openssh -o pem_generated_file.pem
# You should now have the converted key on the directory
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).